# How to use discord python button?

Tags: python

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="A button", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, disabled=False)
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("hello")

@client.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Press the button!", view=MyView())
```

I want to create the button then it reply bac 'hello' or Embed, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.